# Как подключить расширения в php

Tags: php

`Laravel` требует чтобы были установлены следующие `php` расширения:

`BCMath` PHP расширение
Расширение `Ctype` PHP
Расширение `JSON` PHP
Расширение `Mbstring` PHP
Расширение `OpenSSL` PHP
`PDO` PHP расширение
Расширение `Tokenizer` PHP
Расширение `XML` PHP

В `php.ini` есть только `pdo` и `bcmath` как установить остальные? (ос- win10)

Comment: Если для разработки, то есть виртуалка со всем что нужно https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/homestead -- очень удобная штука.

Answer (score 1):

> В Windows есть два способа загрузки PHP-расширения: скомпилировать его
>   вместе с PHP или загрузить DLL. Загрузка заранее скомпилированного
>   расширения является наиболее простым и предпочитаемым способом.
>
> Для загрузки расширения, оно должно присутствовать на вашей системе в
>   виде ".dll" файла. Все расширения автоматически и периодически
>   компилируются командой PHP (см. следующий раздел для загрузки).

Где найти расширение?

> PHP-расширения обычно имеют имена вида "php_*.dll" (где звездочка
>   обозначает имя расширения) и располагаются в папке "PHP\ext".
>
> PHP поставляет расширения наиболее полезные большинству разработчиков.
>   Такие расширения называются "основными" ("core").
>
> Однако, если вам требуется функционал, который не предоставляется ни
>   одним из основных расширений, возможно, нужное вам расширение есть в
>   PECL. Библиотека расширений сообщества PHP (The PHP Extension
>   Community Library, PECL) является хранилищем расширений PHP,
>   предоставляя каталог и хостинг всех известных расширений для скачки и
>   дальнейшей разработки расширений в PHP.

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/install.pecl.windows.php

Установка расширений PECL https://www.php.net/manual/ru/install.pecl.php

What is PECL? https://pecl.php.net/